# Focus not coming on flash object while loading dynamically inside a dialog box?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors

Today i have done a work where i was supposed to show a flash player inside a dialog box. Which i was able to do it quite easily.But my flash player contains a text box which needs to be focused once the flash player is loaded inside the dialog box, but it is not getting focused by default. Can anybody help me to tackle this problem?

But if we click inside the flash player i was able to get the focus, but not by default.

I will show you what i have done up to now

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

</html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="google" value="notranslate">         
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
            html, body  { height:100%; }
            body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto; text-align:center; 
                   background-color: #ffffff; }   
            object:focus { outline:none; }
            #flashContent { display:none; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.11.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a class= "subskillList">test</a>
<!--<div id="activityDialog" class="nodisplay">
    <div class="popup_content">
        <div class="popup-title-header">
            <div class="">
                <span id="dialogTitle" class=""></span><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="closePlayer" title="close" class="close-button">
                    <span class="close-icon">close</span></a></div>
        </div>-->
        <div id="flashContent"></div>
    <!--</div>
</div>-->
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/Javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var languageCode;
    var contentUrl;
    var flashurl;
    $('.subskillList').live('click', function (event) {
        flashEmbed();
        Dialog($('#activityDialog'));
        return false;
    });

    function flashEmbed() {
        var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0";
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "testFocusProject.swf"
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
        params.allowfullscreen = "false";
        params.wmode = "opaque";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "flashApp";
        attributes.name = "testFocusProject";
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
                "testFocusProject.swf", "flashContent",
                "840px", "500px",
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
                flashvars, params, attributes);
                $('#flashApp').tabIndex=0;
                $('#flashApp').focus();
    }

    function setFocusToFlash() {
    $('#flashApp').tabIndex=0;
    $('#flashApp').focus();
    }

    function Dialog(control) {
        $dialog = $(control).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function () {
                var overlaywidth = $('.ui-widget-overlay').width();
                $('.ui-dialog').width(840).height(540);
                var x = $(window).height() / 2 - $('.ui-dialog').height() / 2;
                var y = $(window).width() / 2 - $('.ui-dialog').width() / 2;
                $('.ui-dialog').css('left', y + 'px');
                $('.ui-dialog').css('top', x + $(window).scrollTop() + 'px');
                $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').width(overlaywidth + 20);

                setTimeout(setFocusToFlash(), 2000);
            },
            close: function (ev, ui) {
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').stop().animate({ "opacity": "0" }, 1480);
                $('body').removeAttr('style');
            }
        }).dialog('open');
    }
});
</script>
```

The below code is used to get focus on the flash object

```
setTimeout(setFocusToFlash(), 2000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First  : `swfobject.embedSWF(...)` will need a few milliseconds to embed the swf in HTML. So you can't immediately call  `$('#flashApp').tabIndex=0;` or `$('#flashApp').focus();`

Second : Are you sure `$('#flashApp')` is returning anything.

Third  : `setTimeout(setFocusToFlash(), 2000);` is wrong. It will invoke the function immediately.  Correct is `setTimeout(setFocusToFlash, 2000);`

See how to do it below by fixing these three.

First declare the function like this. This is what works in firefox.

```
function setFocusToFlash() {
    document["flashApp"].tabIndex=0;
    document["flashApp"].focus();
}
```

If its not working `window["flashApp"].focus();` should work in other browsers.

And make use of the ready callback in embedSWF as given below

```
 swfobject.embedSWF(
            "testFocusProject.swf", "flashContent",
            "840px", "500px",
            swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
            flashvars, params, attributes, function(){
                setTimeout(setFocusToFlash, 500);
        });
```

**500ms** was enough for me to get the focus. You can test and set the delay you want.

Comment: Do you use firebug ? Please identify upto where the execution goes. Is there url which I can test ?

Comment: Oops missed this one . `document["flashApp"].tabIndex=0;` See the edited answer.